# Is it possible to update an Android or iPhone app with a completely new source code?

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, google-play

I have several apps in the AppStore and Google Play. They all are built from a framework that I developed a long time ago. Now I have realized that code really needed a clean up, so instead of working on the old framework I decided to build a new one. I am confused if I can update the current apps with the new framework. Is it better to publish a new version of the app or just update current?? Next to that if I update the current one with the new framework (which works completely different), would the app cause any issues (Crashes, Error etc.)?

Thank you.

Comment: This should not be any problem, as long as you keep in mind that file in the user document directory are not wiped on installing the new version. So any database files there will stay there for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Related Android I would say :

As far as your app idea is same you should go for updating the app.
Suppose for example if your app is for just playing music. Now you are making lets say some Flash light then its better to upload flash light separately rather than integrating it with music player. Because music player and flash light are two non-related types.
Later if you want to change the looks or refine the way your app plays the music then you should go for updating your music app.

**Secondly yes you can definitely change the whole source code or inside your "upcoming updated app" but keeping certain things in mind: I hope you are aware of:

1. Package name should be same
2. Version should be incremental
3. If any database structure change use different version other than previous db version: look developer site for more info.

**

Rest you are just good to go.

Comment: Thanks! You mentioned database..The current version uses a database, but the new version won't be using the database anymore. Isn't it so that the complete source code is replaced with the new..So deleted and re-installed?

Comment: to delete a db u have onUpgrade() method 
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion!=newVersion){
        // Remove all old tables and crate new ones
    }
}//your newversion should be greater than oldversion. By this all the tables will be empty with only the schema left or else use context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);

Comment: that I know. It is that in the new code there will be no db at all. The whole source code is built up differently. That is my concern. Will the update handle that?

Comment: no probs dear. Just go ahead keeping the above things(my above answer) in mind and everything will be fine :)